# add block containing JS

Tags: layout, blocks, template, javascript

I would like to add a block containing js to our products page.

The block in question would look like:

```
<script> <?php $this->callfunction($product) ?> </scipt>
```

How would I go about doing this?  And call the 'callfunction' from within this block?

Comment: What does $this->callfunction($product) output?

Comment: @R.S a json encoded array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom module and use `output="toHtml"`

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="content">
       <block type="<name>/catalog_product_callfunction" name="callfunction" output="toHtml"
              template="catalog/product/callfunction.phtml"
              as="callfunction"/>
  </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

in your block

```
class <Company>_<Name>_Block_Catalog_Product_Callfunction extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
{
   public function getCallfunction($product){
     // return json
   } 
}
```

Then in catalog/product/callfunction.phtml

```
<?php $_product = Mage::registry('current_product') ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
     <?php echo $this->getCallfunction($_product); ?>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at default magento /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

You could do

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
```

Comment: my mistake, it's a json-ld encoded array which I have to create myself (which wasn't that hard, I just have trouble with this whole block-layout-template business).  I tried something similar to what you're suggesting, however the original php code I put in the view.  Which isn't very good form as i'm sure you know.

Answer (score 0):

Add phtml for product as reference and on this file you need add your code

On your layout file  **app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtemple/layout/local.xml**   add add phtml  of block type

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view >
        <reference name="content">
         <block type="custommodule/custommodule" name="myscript"  template="catalog/product/myscript.phtml"/>
     </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtemple/temple/catalog/product/myscript.phtml file code add your code

```
    <?php
if(Mage::registry('current_product')){
<script type="text/javascript">
     <?php echo $this->getCallfunction((Mage::registry('current_product')); ?>
</script>
}
?>
```

callfunction fean it a function of clas so you need to create a custom module

Step1:

First of all create module control file Module name as  Amit_Custommodule.xml at app/etc/modules/ and code is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Custommodule>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </Amit_Custommodule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Step2:Path Of config.xml is app/code/community/Amit/Custommodule/etc/  and create block aclass and here i define block class

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Custommodule>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Amit_Custommodule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <!-- start of block -->
        <blocks>
            <custommodule>
                <class>Amit_Custommodule_Block</class>
            </custommodule>
        </blocks>
    </global>

</config>
```

**Step3:** Create `Custommodule.php`  located in `app\code\community\Amit\Custommodule\Block` and 
`Amit_Custommodule_Block_Custommodule` is extends `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View` and here on this custom class and here i am encode some product data

```
 <?php
class Amit_Custommodule_Block_Custommodule extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View{

    public function callfunction($product){
    $arr=array(
    'name'=> $product->getName(),
    'sku' =>$product->getSku(),
    );
    json_encode($arr);

    }
}
```

Comment: Where should callfunction() be located?

Comment: can u tell on callfunction function what will  be  json encoded array

Comment: yes.  I can tell what will be encoded -- I created the function.  I"m just unsure how to implement it.